# React native zoom in effect when click item in grid view to detail view list

Tags: reactjs, listview, gridview, native

I'm new with react native, and I'm trying to achieve the exact same effect as Instagram or TikTok when you click an item in a gridview it opens up a listview with details of the items with a zoom in effect.

For now, I have a gridview, where data load with a limit of 10 items and when reaching the end gets the next 10 items. In order to try and achieve what I want to do, been searching but can't seem to figure out the right approach.

Should I have both list in the same screen, but how do I get the app to do the zoom in effect and open the detail view at the right index item ? Or should I have both list in separate views, but how do I keep the data synced ? Or is there another way that I'm missing and keep seem to find ?

[Image might help understand (taken from instagram)](https://i.stack.imgur.com/s9313.jpg)

Comment: @A Ber have you solved this problem.

Comment: @AnuragShrivastava sorry for the delay. Not yet, found a lead but haven't had the time try it out.